# How to pass values statically from one page to other in android?

Tags: android

In my projects I kept **different images** for **categories**. When I click on each **category image** I am passing its **category id** to other page **statically** and setting the **drawable image** of that category in the **new page**.

**My Code:**

**Firstpage.java**

```
public static String categoryid;

category1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
{
   public void onClick(View view)
    {
     categoryid="0";
     Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(),Nextpage.class);
     startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
    }
});
category2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
{
   public void onClick(View view)
   {
    categoryid="1";
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(),Nextpage.class);
    startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
   }
});
category3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
{
   public void onClick(View view)
   {
    categoryid="2";
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(),Nextpage.class);
    startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
   }
});
```

**Nextpage.java**

```
public static String catid = Firstpage.categoryid;
          ImageView categorytype=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

             if(catid=="0")
            { 
                categorytype.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.image1);
            }

             else if(catid=="1")
            { 
                categorytype.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.image2);
            }
           else  if(catid=="2")
            {
                   categorytype.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.image3);
            }
```

First time when I am clicking on the **category image** it is passing the **category id** to the next page and that particular image is setting in the nextpage. After that I clicked the back button(android back button) and went to Firstpage.java and again clicked on other image. But this time also the same image stored. The category id didnt changed. The category id is not refreshing...How to refresh the category id? Any suggestion will be thankful.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use static variables for this. Pass the category ID to your `Nextpage` activity through the intent. In Firstpage.java:

```
public static final String CATEGORY_KEY = "category";

category1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
{
   public void onClick(View view)
    {
     Intent myIntent = new Intent(this,Nextpage.class);
     myIntent.putExtra(CATEGORY_KEY, "0");
     startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
    }
});
```

Then retrieve it in the `onCreate(Bundle)` method of Nextpage.java:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String categoryid = intent.getStringExtra(Firstpage.CATEGORY_KEY);
    . . .
}
```

The reason your method doesn't work is that `Nextpage.catid` is initialized when the class is loaded, but the assignment statement is not executed again unless the class is unloaded and needs to be reloaded.

Comment: Hi thank you...I have passed the value through the intent. Now its working fine....

Answer (score 1):

You are comparing two strings by == operator, instead you should compare by equals method, try following:

```
if(catid.equals("0"))
            { 
                categorytype.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.image1);
            }

             else if(catid.equals("1"))
            { 
                categorytype.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.image2);
            }
           else  if(catid.equals(2"))
            {
                   categorytype.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.image3);
            }
```

Comment: That's not the problem. OP is using string literals, so in this case == would actually work because of String interning.

Answer (score 0):

I think problem is here you are comparing String values using this `if(catid=="0")` Which you should be compare it using `if(catid.trim().equals("0"))`

Update this change in your code and check it.

Comment: OP is using string literals, so in this case `==` would actually work because of String interning. The problem is that `Nextpage.catid` only gets set once.